# Invertibility of operator $-\Delta -\lambda_{1} I: W_{*}^{2,p}(\Omega)\rightarrow L_{*}^{p}(\Omega)$

Tags: laplacian, elliptic-operators

The operator $-\Delta -\lambda_{1} I: W_{*}^{2,p}(\Omega)\rightarrow  L_{*}^{p}(\Omega)$ is invertible?  $W_{*}^{2,p}(\Omega)=\{u\in W^{2,p}(\Omega);\int_{\Omega}u\varphi_{1}dx=0\}, \,L_{*}^{p}(\Omega)=\{u\in L^{p}(\Omega);\int _{\Omega}u\varphi_{1}dx=0\}$, where $\varphi_{1}$ is the first eigenfunction associated with the first eigenvalue of the Laplacian.

Comment: assume that  $1<p<n$.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by $W^{2,p}_*$. Do you want it to be the subspace of $W^{2,p}$ with that property? (For $p=2$, the orthogonal complement of the span of a first eigenfunction.)